# How to disable ember-fastboot after site already loaded locally?

Tags: ember.js

This is related to a [post I recently made regarding ember-fastboot and saving a webpage for offline viewing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53108846/how-to-save-a-webpage-offline-that-is-rendered-with-ember-cli-fastboot).

I am making a separate post because I believe this is more an **ember-fastboot** question and isn't specific to the website I am trying to save for offline viewing.

**Basically, I am trying to find out how, on the local end, to completely override ember**. That is, since I already have open in my browser the rendered page, what does one need to do in order to save the page such that when opened later locally as offline page, the page appears the same way it did when rendered in the first place?

It seems like I am in a paradox. I have a rendered page, with content such as a javascript media player. I save rendered page. I then open the locally saved, rendered page but then the ember javascript kicks in and alters the page, such that the javascript media player no longer loads, due to ember altering a div's class name to specify that the player is not booted! The thing is, once rendered, I don't need ember doing anything, as I am just interested in viewing a frozen copy of the rendered page with no interest in subsequent connections to the rendering server.

Anyway, hope someone can shed some light on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you control the page? Or do you want to "use* that page?

Comment: Hi, I don't control the page, but when it loads I have all the resources needed to view.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove `<script>` tags from the `index.html` after saving it. That would prevent the app from starting, leaving the pre-rendered HTML intact.

You might need to split the JS bundle if you need a JS player to be running independently. Splitting the bundle is an advanced technique. If you need it, please ask a separate question.

Comment: There seems to be an insane amount of mixins related to the javaplayer and related functionality. I tried removing script tag but it just seems like needle and haystack problem to figure out what other pieces like jquery, etc, are all part of the inner working of the js player.